# Javascript, use function as recursion deep counter

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use a function as a recursion counter? I try to make recursion with deep counter, given from another object. For some situation it will be number, for another string concatenation. For example - exchange deepLevel + 1 in every call for deep.inc().
But in that case I have no proper value on the stack...

```
const render = (formatterData, parcedData) => {
  const iter = (depth, data) => {
    const mapped = data.map((node) => {
      const { children = [] } = node;
      const renderedChildren = children.length > 0 ? iter(depth.inc(), children) : '';
      return `${formatterData.format(depth, node, renderedChildren)}`;
    });

    return `${mapped.join('')}`;
  };
  return `${formatterData.startElement}${iter(formatterData.depth, parcedData)}\n${formatterData.endElement}`;
};
```

FormatterData is the object given by render and depends of the render type.

```
const formatterData = {
  startElement: '{',
  endElement: '}',

  depth: {
    level: 1,
    get() {
      return this.level;
    },
    inc() {
      this.level += 1;
      return this;
    },
  },
  format(depth, node, line) {
    const { nodeRender } = getNodeRender(node);
    return `${nodeRender(node, depth, line)}`;
  },
};

    Now part of console output looks like:
    depth =  {"level":2}
    depth =  {"level":3}
    depth =  {"level":3}
    depth =  {"level":4}
    depth =  {"level":5}
    depth =  {"level":6}
    depth =  {"level":7}
    depth =  {"level":8}
    depth =  {"level":9}
    depth =  {"level":10}

but should be:
    depth =  {"level":2}
    depth =  {"level":3}
    depth =  {"level":4}
    depth =  {"level":5}
    depth =  {"level":4}
    depth =  {"level":3}
    depth =  {"level":2}
```

Comment: do you have some data to show the wanted result? maybe some code, you tried as well?

Comment: Your code should work. What part of it is not working as you expect it to?

Comment: This question is very unclear and needs some clarification

Comment: btw, what is `f1` doing?

Comment: I made some changes and posted part of code

Comment: please add a call of the function and the wanted result.

Comment: Output added to the question body

Comment: i have still no idea how to call the whole stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Yup you can do like

```
const f = (deep, something) => {
 .....
 var n = parseInt(deep);
 f1(deep, something);
 return f(deep +1, something);
}
```

and it is possible to do that in Javascript